# Socket is closed after reading from it's InputStream

Tags: java, sockets, java-stream

Method to send message to peer:

```
    public static void writeLineToPeer(Peer peer, String message) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(peer.getSocket().getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        
        writer.write(message + "\n");
        writer.flush();
    }
```

Reading the response:

```
public class PeersResponse extends Response<Peer>
{
    public PeersResponse(InputStream stream) throws InvalidMessageException, IOException
    {
        super(stream);
        parseResponse();
        getNextElement();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void parseResponse() throws InvalidMessageException, IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.stream, "UTF-8"));
        
        setVersion(reader.readLine());
            
        setAmount(reader.readLine());
        //Fine until here
    }

    @Override
    public Peer getNextElement() throws InvalidMessageException, IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.stream, "UTF-8"));
        
        String ip = reader.readLine();
        //Socket exception: Socket is closed

        if (NetworkHelper.isValidIPAddress(ip))
        {
            throw new InvalidMessageException();
        }
            
        String port = reader.readLine();
            
        String typeOfPeer = reader.readLine();
    
        if (typeOfPeer.length() != 1)
        {
            throw new InvalidMessageException();
        }
            
        try
        {
            return PeerFactory.getPeer(typeOfPeer.charAt(0), ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidMessageException(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see I get a Socket exception: Socket is closed when trying to read from another instance of a
BufferedReader with the same InputStream.

The message that is being sent is fine and fits the structure of this class.

What's the cause of this? How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe `this.stream` is being closed after `parseResponse()` returns. You should not be creating multiple readers on a single stream, you should either have an instance level reader or `PeersResponse`'s methods should have a `BufferedReader reader` parameter. Furthermore, `BufferedReader#readLine` can return `null` if there's nothing left to read, you should check for `null` in case of an ill formed message (especially with regard to `if (typeOfPeer.length() != 1) // <-- NullPointerException`).

Comment: I've tried creating an instance-level reader and using it on both `parseResponse()` and `getNextElement()` but I still get the same exception.
Thanks for the tip, I'll make sure to null check.

Comment: In that case there must be something wrong with the message being received or something is happening with the socket in a different part of your code not shown here. Have you checked the results of `setVersion(...)` and `setAmount(...)`, if they get set to what you expect?

Comment: You should probably use the same BufferedReader rather than recreating it. Do you close it? Closing it would close the underlying inputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you call `reader.ReadLine()` inside of `parseResponse()` the `BufferedReader`  reads a chunk of data from the stream. It reads more than just one line, because it does not yet know where the end of line is. The only way for it to read (and remove) just one line from the socket would be to read characters one-by-one and stop when it sees the new line. But that would defeat the purpose of using `BufferedReader`  in the first place.

The second time you call `reader.ReadLine()` inside of `parseResponse()`, it does not read from the underlying socket at all. It just parses the data already stored inside `BufferedReader`  and returns the next line.

At the time `parseResponse()` exits, there is still data stored inside `BufferedReader`. As the reader variable goes out of scope, that data is lost. It cannot be read from the socket, because it has already been read from the socket.

**TLDR;**
You can step through `parseResponse()` in the debugger **and look inside the** `reader` **instance** (examine JDK's internal data structure). You will see your entire message there. And you will see how the remainder of your message gets lost when `parseResponse()` returns.

Comment: So basically the whole message loads into the memory?

Comment: If the message is small enough and was sent all at once, the whole message loads into memory.

Comment: I am writing multiple times into the OutputStream, so it does not load everything into the memory, right?

Comment: It may or may not read the *whole* message. But in almost cases it will read more than just the version and the amount into memory. Even if you don't write the whole message at once, it may still load the whole message into memory. There is a lot of variability here.

Comment: You will gain a lot of insight by putting a breakpoint inside parseResponse() and examining the reader variable.